# Is there anything unique bound to Java installation?

Tags: java, encryption

I need to save user's password to remote service locally. The remote service doesn't support any API for remembering login, so I have to store the password symmetrically encrypted. In fact, I'm making a desktop automation program that literally enters the password into the field.

It's not possible to save locally a password securely - if your program can decrypt it, any other can too. But you can for example make sure that user's settings cannot be decrypted outside of his computer. To do this, people use various hardware/software ID's. I, as many others, elected for MAC address for now. But I was wondering:

Does local Java installation store some constant unique information? Note that Java version is not constant, I meant something like random ID generated during first installation.

Comment: AFAIK there's no such thing in Java, you should use some OS service for that, which usually has access to TPM and other similar stuff.

Comment: TPM? I hoped there would be OS services indeed, something at least a little secure. MAC addresses are very problematic as there are multiple network devices and they can change in both order and count (especially on notebooks).

Comment: Not every computer has TPM (especially cheaper ones lack this feature) and everything else can be copied by simply taking the disk. You could argue of course that users that care about secure storage would be using FDE integrated into every modern mainstream OS anyway...